# IOError 22 in python Invalid on windows

Tags: python, windows, file, ioerror

I'm creating a sniffer for serial port in python, but I have a problem when i create a CSV file in windows. I split my program  on some point to avoid the possibility of incompatibility between windows and linux. It's works perfectly on linux (test on 32 and 64 bytes).

```
def createNewFiles(self):
    # Nons allons vérifier l'existance du dossier Sniffer_Serie_Result et le créer si besoin
    # De même pour le fichier csv
    if (os.name == "nt"): # pour windows
        self.userPath = os.getenv('HOME') or os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
        self.folderPath= os.path.abspath(self.userPath + "\\Sniffer_Serie_Result")
        #exist_ok=True ==> cree le dossier si il n'existe pas
        os.makedirs(self.folderPath,exist_ok=True)
        self.timestampWithSec= self.timestampWithoutMilli() # utilisé dans les noms de fichier
        self.filePathRequest= os.path.abspath(self.folderPath + "\\Request_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv")
        self.filePathResponse= os.path.abspath(self.folderPath + "\\Response_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv")
        self.filePathOverall = os.path.abspath(self.folderPath + "\\Overall_result_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv")
        with open(self.filePathRequest, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["Kind of message","Timestamp","Message Hexa","Message ASCII"]) 
        with open(self.filePathResponse, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["Kind of message","Timestamp","Message Hexa","Message ASCII"])
```

The folder Sniffer_Serie_Result is create without error
So this code return the following error at the first with:

IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Documents and Settings\stagiaire\Sniffer_Serie_Result\Request_at_......(Actual date and hours).csv'

I try lot of string like raw string and nothing works.

NB: The windows i use for my test is XP, this need to work on 7 too

I hope you can help me.
Tks for your help!

I can't give no more information before thursday (no internet at home for the moment)

Comment: First of all, use `os.path.join()` to concatenate directories rather than adding slashes by hand. Secondly, what does `timestampWithSec` contain?

Comment: Hi, I will try this, the timstamp contain the time in str.

Comment: So I try your solution but the error this exactly the same

Comment: I meant: please paste example contents of `timestampWithSec`. I suspect it simply contains some characters which are invalid for Windows.

Comment: Example of file name on linux (the name are the same one both system): Request_at_2012-08-14_14:41:30.csv so Timestamp containt exactly: 2012-08-14_14:41:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `:` characters in filename, while that character is reserved in Windows for drive names (e.g. `c:/`).

You have to either:

1. Modify `timestampWithoutMilli()` to use another time separator (like `-`),
2. Substitute all `:` in obtained time string with another character (using `.replace()`), for example.

Comment: Just for that !!! 2 days on this error .I test . I can't vote up sorry ... your response can help other people

Comment: To be honest, I think it's quite a common mistake. I'm pretty sure I've seen it here already.

Comment: Yes maybe I search on french forums ans english forums and you are the first who can help me ...

Comment: To avoid this later, make sure you use `try/except` to let the operating system sort out valid filenames or not.

Comment: The exception are more precise than the classique traceback ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting unescaped \ in userPath. Try changing all \ to /.

Comment: I add some precision, In a new com with the code. If i use os.path.abspath() the path is the same than before so  i try without this.

Answer (score -1):

```
def createNewFiles(self):
        # Nons allons vérifier l'existance du dossier Sniffer_Serie_Result et le créer si besoin
        # De même pour le fichier csv
        if (os.name == "nt"): # pour windows
            self.userPath = os.getenv('HOME') or os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
            self.folderPath= self.userPath + "/Sniffer_Serie_Result"
            #exist_ok=True ==> cree le dossier si il n'existe pas
            os.makedirs(self.folderPath,exist_ok=True)
            self.timestampWithSec= self.timestampWithoutMilli() # utilisé dans les noms de fichier
            self.filePathRequest= self.folderPath + "/Request_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv"
            self.filePathResponse= self.folderPath + "/Response_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv"
            self.filePathOverall = self.folderPath + "/Overall_result_at_" + self.timestampWithSec + ".csv"
            with open(self.filePathRequest, 'w') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(["Kind of message","Timestamp","Message Hexa","Message ASCII"]) 
            with open(self.filePathResponse, 'w') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(["Kind of message","Timestamp","Message Hexa","Message ASCII"])
```

With this code the probleem is exactly the same, the folder is createbut not the files. With the same error.